# Copy the contents of Custom Field to external_identfier field for all contacts

Tags: custom-fields, external-id

Loving civicrm, just getting to grips with it. I've imported a load of contacts but I've made a rookie error and instead of importing my unique ID number for each contact into the 'external_identifier' field I created my own custom field and imported it there. Unfortunately, I have so many contacts the Surname/First Name are not unique, only the custom unique ID is truly the way to distinguish individual contacts from each other. Is there a way to copy all the data across from my custom unique ID field to 'external_identifier'? I've tried doing this with a SQL query in phpmyadmin but having no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with the API explorer. Go to **Support -> Developer -> API Explorer v4** and enter settings exactly like this, except the three places where I refer to "constituent_information.my_id_field" you need to change it with the *exact* identifier of your custom field (to make sure you got it right, pick it from the "Add Select" list and then you can copy-paste it into the "chain" section):

[image: APIv4 Explorer]

PS the code in that "chain" section is a lot so here it is for you to copy (this part needs a dollar sign before the name of your field, but the Select section does not):

```
{where: [[id, =, $id]], values: {external_identifier: $constituent_information.my_id_field}}
```